# Greasemonkey - removing div class(absolute beginner)

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I've been told that if I want tips to alterations of a specific link I should ask here. I've already viewed a few topics, but I couldn't make the suggestions there work for me.

I wish to remove: `<div class="validation_ticker">` and everything within it(all the code in the code box):

```
<div class="validation_ticker">
 <div class="validation_ticker_align">
  <div class="validation_ticker_icon"></div>
  <div class="validation_ticker_msg" style="line-height:1.1em">
   Is <a href="/account/editprofile">mymail@gmail.com</a> still your email address? Please <form action="/account/revalidate_email" method="post" id="revalidate_email" style="display: inline; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><button style="display:  inline; border: 0; border-style: none; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; background-image: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: normal; list-style: none outside none; text-decoration: none; width: auto; height: auto; font-size: 13px; color: #ffff00" type="submit" value="click here">click here</button></form> to re-validate your account or <a href="/account/editprofile">change your address</a>.<br>
   Not seeing email? Check your SPAM folder and mark as "NOT SPAM"!
   <script type="text/javascript">

   jQuery(function($) {
        $('#revalidate_email').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(true);
        return false;
        });
   });
```

It is a verification banner at the top of the screen. The site wants E-mail verification regularly, but I'm not too keen on that, I often mistake it for phishing too.

**EDIT2: Code updated to working version**

This is what I've come up with from the advise I was given by Ashkan:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Script Name
// @namespace   namespace
// @include     http://www.X.com/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
$('.validation_ticker').remove();
```

Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that jQuery is added to your script at the top of the script:

`// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`

Use the jQuery `remove` function:

```
$('.validation_ticker').remove();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I've edited the parent post. Would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: This code is correct for sure. If its not working may be jQuery is not added to your script. Are you sure jQuery is referenced?  you should have this line in your code: `/ @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: That worked like a charm. The bar is gone. Thank you for your help. I have less than 15 rep so you can't see my vote, but I did vote. Would appreciate if others did too.

Comment: Not used to the site. Didn't know the checkmark was marking as answer. I figured out as much just before seeing your reply here ^^

Answer (score 2):

CSS example:
`.validation_ticker {visibility: hidden; }`

Comment: How would I use this line in a script with greasemonkey? Would this still leave the room for the bar up top, but just invisible? Or would it remove the body of the bar and let the rest of the page look normal. Sorry that you have to spoon-feed me, but I don't know a lick of programming, I'm just trying to suck up the knowledge I can from existing threads here and it's not going so well atm.

Comment: My issue is resolved, but I'm still kinda curious in knowing how your line would work with a Greasemonkey script, if it's something you want to explain of course.

Comment: The css snippet would hide the element. If you do not have access to the css page, and you cannot link to an external stylesheet,  you could use an inline style, such as `<div style="visibility: hidden;">This is a Blue Heading</div>` to hide the banner. This would not effect the layout. The element still exists, it's just not seen.

Comment: Then I know the difference for the next time I'm going to use these commands. In this case removing was the right way to go. It was a header that was inserted above the site, pushing the rest down. Appreciate the explanation.